# Testing For A Picture In Certain Cells In A Selected Range

Tags: excel, vba

Certain cells in a range in excel have picture. Is there a straight way to loop through each cell in that selected range and identify cells which have picture?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Sub findCellsWithShapes()
Dim sh As Shape, isect
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    'Set isect = Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, Range("A2:H10"))
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, Selection)
    If Not isect Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox sh.TopLeftCell.Address
    End If
Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: Set isect = Application.Intersect(sh.TopLeftCell, Selection) - does not work if there are objects in cells other than selected ones.

Comment: can you post a link to a sample file ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zotg08q6642lmbc/Sample%20File.xlsm?dl=0 Link to sample file

Comment: No images in your file, only links to images

Comment: I tested the download and confirm that images are there in the file in column D, Column C. Try following link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/93767612cac0ad585820b1adbedee54a20191023124552/ad4d0b

Comment: I'm sorry, no images, test your file with another pc

Comment: Tested on another laptop. objects - pictures are there, for example, in cells - D7, D8, D9, A8, B17, B21, A23.

Comment: I can not see them, only links

Comment: Can you suggest any other method of sharing this sample file? I tried wetransfer site and dropbox but both have yielded same result. You are not able to see the pictures in cells.